# Unicode characters in Python 3 vs Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I have written a simple script in python 2 to train my knowledge of hiragana letters. Please see the code below :

```
import random

ROMAJI = ['A','I','U','E','O','KA','KI','KU','KE','KO','SA','SHI','SU','SE','SO','TA','CHI','TSU','TE','TO','NA','NI','NU','NE','NO']

romaji_letter = random.choice(ROMAJI)
romaji_index = ROMAJI.index(romaji_letter)

A = u'\u3042'
I = u'\u3044'
U = u'\u3046'
E = u'\u3048'
O = u'\u304A'
KA = u'\u304B'
KI = u'\u304D'
KU = u'\u304F'
KE = u'\u3051'
KO = u'\u3053'
SA = u'\u3055'
SHI = u'\u3057'
SU = u'\u3059'
SE = u'\u305B'
SO = u'\u305D'
TA = u'\u305F'
CHI = u'\u3061'
TSU = u'\u3064'
TE = u'\u3066'
TO = u'\u3068'
NA = u'\u306A'
NI = u'\u306B'
NU = u'\u306C'
NE = u'\u306D'
NO = u'\u306E'

HIRAGANA = [A,I,U,E,O,KA,KI,KU,KE,KO,SA,SHI,SU,SE,SO,TA,CHI,TSU,TE,TO,NA,NI,NU,NE,NO]

print("\nWhich Hiragana character is the Romaji letter " + romaji_letter + " ?\n")

for letter in HIRAGANA:
        print(letter.encode("UTF-8")+"     "+str(HIRAGANA.index(letter))+"\n")


print("Choose the corresponding number and press [ENTER] : ")

userInput = raw_input()

try:
        letter_index = int(userInput)
        print("You have chosen letter "+HIRAGANA[letter_index].encode("UTF-8"))

        if ( letter_index == romaji_index):
                print("The answer is correct!")
        else:
                print("The answer is incorrect!")

except:
        print("Enter only the number of the corresponding letters!")
```

When I execute this in python 2 it does work without problem. However when I try with python 3 I get the following error :

```
"Can't concat bytes to str"
```

Can someone help by explaining why is it happening?

Oh, not sure if it does matter, but I am using python 2 on fedora and python 3 on Windows 7 ( with Visual Studio 2012 along with python tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be encoding your characters to UTF-8. Leave encoding to the `print()` call:

```
for letter in HIRAGANA:
    print(letter + u"     " + str(HIRAGANA.index(letter)) + u"\n")
```

and:

```
print(u"You have chosen letter " + HIRAGANA[letter_index])
```

because strings in Python 3 are all Unicode values, not bytes values, but encoding always produces bytes.

Better still, use string formatting and `enumerate()` here:

```
for index, letter in enumerate(HIRAGANA):
    print(u"{}     {}\n".format(letter, index))
```

and

```
print(u"You have chosen letter {}".format(HIRAGANA[letter_index]))
```

Next, `raw_input()` is not available in Python 3, you'd have to use `input()` there. You can use exceptions to detect which one to use:

```
try:
    raw_input
except NameError:
    raw_input = input  # Python 3
```

Comment: I have one more question for you if i may ask, and this one is weird to me. When i used your solution in python 3.4.2 shell it worked flawlessly, but when i used it in Visual Studio i get the following error : 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u3042' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>. Does python tools for visual studio work differently?

Comment: @sztyrymytyry: the console in Visual Studio is configured to a different codepage. It cannot handle all Unicode output until you reconfigure it.